# How to use quosure in ggplot to generate plotting function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data set where I need to generate multiple plots based on different columns, so instead of copy/pasting, I am trying to write a function, where I pass the function the dataframe and the column name.   I am pretty sure that this requires a quosure, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work in ggplot2.

Ideally, I would be able to pass the dataframe, RawData, and the column name (B in this case) and it would generate a bar plot using column B, and including the column B label on the plot. For example.

```
RawData = data.frame(A = runif(12, 0, 5), B = LETTERS[seq(1,4)], C = letters[seq(3,1)])

ggplot(RawData, aes(x=A,y=B))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  xlab("Group")+ylab("B")
```

The function I wrote is effectively this...

```
PlotFn  = function(df, VarName) {
  VarName = quo(VarName)
  ggplot(df, aes(x=A,y=!!VarName))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  xlab("Group")+ylab(as_label(!!VarName))
}

PlotFn(RawData, B)
```

Which throws the error:

> Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.
>
> # Bad:
>    list(!!myquosure)
>
> # Good:
>    dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)

Ideally I would be able to have my plot function run

```
PlotFn(RawData, B)

PlotFn(RawData, C)
```

and give bar plots that are labeled appropriately, like the one here.

Comment: Good review here: https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to unquote (`!!`) `VarName`

```r
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

RawData = data.frame(A = runif(12, 0, 5), 
                     B = LETTERS[seq(1,4)], 
                     C = letters[seq(3,1)])

PlotFn <- function(df, .VarName) {
  VarName <- enquo(.VarName)
  ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = !!VarName)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    ylab(as_label(VarName)) +
    xlab("Group")
}
PlotFn(RawData, C)
```

[image]

I personally prefer `.data[[]]` like this

```r
PlotFn2 <- function(df, .VarName) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = .data[[.VarName]])) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    ylab(.VarName) +
    xlab("Group")
}

plot_list <- c("B", "C") %>% 
  map(~ PlotFn2(RawData, .x))
plot_list
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```r
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Another [option](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#best-practices-for-common-tasks) you could add to your answer is `PlotFn <- function(df, .VarName) { ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = {{ .VarName. }})) }`.

Comment: @TimTeaFan: thanks for the reminder! I kept forgetting about the new `rlang`'s function

Comment: @Tung, thank you, this is pretty confusing, somehow I couldn't get this to go the way I thought it might.  You use the rlang to say .VarName right?  I just tried to run with `PlotFn  = function(df, VarName) {
VarName = enquo(VarName)
ggplot(df, aes(x=A,y=!!VarName))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+ 
  xlab("Group")+ylab(as_label(VarName))
 }` and it worked, but didn't  need rlang, am I right on this?

Comment: @EBrewe: no you don't need `rlang`. Only needed if you use curly-curly `{{ }}` as TimTeaFan mentioned above